# python - elegant way to pick the highest weighted value in set

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have a list such that

```
l = ['xyz','abc','mnq','qpr']
```

These values are weighted such that `xyz>abc>mnq>qpr`
I have a pandas dataframe with a column that has sets of values.

```
                      COL_NAME    
0         set(['xyz', 'abc'])     
1         set(['xyz']) 
2         set(['mnq','qpr'])
```

Now, I want to pick the highest values in the sets such that after I apply the custom function I am left with

```
                  COL_NAME    
0         set(['xyz'])     
1         set(['xyz']) 
2         set(['mnq'])
```

Is there an elegant way to do this process without resorting to a dictionary of weights?

Comment: If you can make your custom function into a key function then you can probably do something like `{max({'xyz', 'abc'}, key=your_function)}`

Comment: sorry I edited my question a little. Hopefully, I am making much more sense now. I have a need for the functionality described above but I am not sure of the best way to go about doing it

Comment: Write a function that will return the max value based on the weights - then use max() to extract it.

Comment: ```I am not sure of the best way to go about doing it``` - just try something and if you run into problems, come back and 
ask specific questions about those problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [`pd.Categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Categorical.html#pandas.Categorical) with the parameter `ordered=True` and set the `categories=l[::-1]` to get the order you'd like.

```
def max_cat(x):
    return set([pd.Categorical(x, l[::-1], True).max()])

df.COL_NAME.apply(max_cat)

0    {xyz}
1    {xyz}
2    {mnq}
Name: COL_NAME, dtype: object
```

Comment: Added link. Hope you don't object.

Comment: @MadPhysicist not at all

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I may have a follow up question :) Just one errata though - the return value should be  set([pd.Categorical(x, l[::-1], True).max()]). If you don't use the square brackets it converts the string into a set of individual characters so intead of getting set(['xyz']), I would get set(['y', 'x', 'z'])

Comment: @Fizi yeah I fixed that on my end.  Forgot to update answer.  Thx for catching that.